# C# char 16 bit container

Tags: c#

I was reading the [msdn char reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x9h8tsay.aspx)

Quite interestingly it states:

> The value of a **Char** object is a 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value

To me this is saying, that you can store any encoded character in this object as long as it's representation is 16 bit. Is my understanding correct?

Does this mean that UTF-32 can't be represented in a char object?

---

#### Edit

This is not limited to UTF-32, I couldn't care less about handling it. Its the only char encoding I know that uses 32 bits.

Comment: You can use a char like an integer for certain types of operations, for example `int x = '9' - '1'; // = 8`. About the second part: You can use `Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes()` to convert your UTF-16 c# string to UTF-32. Just because .NET uses UTF-16 internally doesn't mean you are stuck with it.

Comment: @JoeEnos This isn't a duplicate, it's not specific around 32 bit unicode charaters. It's about understanding the char object c#

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @Phylogenesis this isn't about unicode and character sets....

Comment: Why in tarnation would you *want* to store some other value in a `char`? You can use `short` or `ushort` if you want a general purpose 16-bit variable. Otherwise you'd just be creating harder-than-necessary-to-maintain code.

Comment: 16-bit is the internal representation of the Unicode characters. UTF-32 is an encoding. With surrogate pairs every Unicode character can be represented.

Comment: @CallumLinington Then what *is* it about? StackOverflow is for asking questions about something specific. You had a specific question and now it seems like you're turning it into something way too broad for SO.

Comment: I think the answer to your question is simply **no** then

Comment: @itsme86 it's about understanding the char object, I think Phylogenesis 2nd comment clears it up somewhat

Comment: Also, it should be noted that the most popular encoding of Unicode (UTF-8) also encodes some characters as 4 bytes.

Comment: @Phylogenesis So when it comes to ASCII encoded chars, it just stores it's ordinal bytes in the char container because 16 bit is more than enough space

Comment: Not quite. Everything is stored internally as Unicode codepoints. The first 127 codepoints happen to match the ASCII character set, but that is fairly incidental.

Comment: @Phylogenesis yeah so what I was thinking, was that I suspect each `Encoding.GetString` is doing a unicode 16-bit conversion under the hood, because strings in .NET are UTF-16.

Comment: Under the hood, it uses `Encoding.GetChars` So it is relying on the underlying encoding to do the conversion to UTF-16

Comment: It just takes *two* chars to represent a codepoint in the upper bit planes.  That isn't otherwise special, it also takes two chars to represent glyphs with diacritics that are not special-cased to a single codepoint.  Or more, google "zalgo" for silly tricks.  It is the job of the text rendering engine to take care of this.